# Is there a JQuery tooltip plugin that supports HTML content and automatically positions tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am searching for a Tooltip plugin/library for JQuery. It should be able to automaticlly position tooltips, like [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin), and also support HTML content for the tips.

TipTip does fullfill both conditions, but:

> Added HTML support with Tip Tip. You can now add HTML into the Title attribute (though this is not recommended if you want strictly valid code).

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) does. For instance, [this demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/#tonus) shows an image. You could easily have a `bodyHandler` that retrieves the HTML from an attribute on the element. For instance

```
<a href="whatever" data-tooltip="This is a <strong>marked up</strong> tooltip">foo</a>
```

That's perfectly valid HTML, and the `bodyHandler` would look something like

```
return this.attr("data-tooltip"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to leave jquery native plugin and mess with additional libs, so I figured out quite simple solution:

```
$('.tooltips').tooltip({
        content: function(){
            return $(this).attr('title');
        }
    })
```

This way - your title attribute with HTML may be used successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I like TipTip a lot. The "title" field usage is awkward, but you don't have to do that:

*content: string (false by default) - HTML or String to use as the content for TipTip. Will overwrite content from any HTML attribute.*

(via http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

This tooltip widget included in the jQuery UI library supports different automatic positions and HTML in the title attribute: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/