# jQuery select for element variable

Tags: jquery, positioning

I haven't been able to find an answer to this:

My HTML (simplified) looks similar to this (there are several different controls on the page: text fields, comboboxes, etc.):

```
...
<input name="name" onfocus="showHint(this, 'Please enter your name')" onblur="hideHint()" ...>
...
```

An in the javascript function `showHint` I do something like:

```
function showFormEntryHint(control, text)
{
    localOffset = 30;
    $('#entry_hint').html(text);
    var position = $(control).offset();
    position.left += $(this).offset() + localOffset;
    position.top -= 5;
    $('#entry_hint').position(position);
    $('#entry_hint').fadeIn();
}
```

The idea is to position the `#entry_hint` div next to the field that invoked the function.  Unfortunately, selector `$(control)` does not seem to work - and `.offset()` on it always returns `{left: 0, top: 0}`.

Any idea how I can get this to work?  Many thanks!

Comment: I would recommend a nice pre-baked tooltip library.

Comment: @thomasfedb: that would be nice, but the stuff that we need to stick into that tooltip is much more than just text.  It would essentially be ajax-loaded xml/xslt.

Comment: Just a quick question - why not have a class for the input fields, and define the events in your script block? :)

Comment: @Jeff: we might end up doing this.  I would still have to define each one individually though, as the second parameter (details for the hint) are field-specific.

Comment: @Aleks G, there should be tooltips available that can accomodate this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643964/is-there-a-jquery-tooltip-plugin-that-supports-html-content-and-automatically-pos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well just get rid of the control and you can use $(this) like you do for position.left. not sure what you are trying to accomplish with $(control).

Comment: Not sure how exactly this would work.  I have a dozen controls on the page - when `showHint` it invoked, the control, which invoked it is passed as the parameter.  Would woud `$(this)` evaluate to?

Comment: position.left += $(this).offset() + localOffset; for this line you use $(this), which should be equivalent to what you are trying to accomplish with $(control) because for control you are just passing it "this" in the first place...

Comment: Yes! Apparently, this was exactly the problem.  I missed this `$(this)`!  When I replaced the line with `position.left += $(control).width() + localOffset;` - everything worked perfectly.  Although you didn't answer my question directly, you did point me to the source of the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You're using jQuery anyway; why stick to DOM0-style event handlers?

Do it like this:

```
<!-- simplified -->
<input id='someInput' />

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($) {

    // this is where we attach the event handlers
    $('input#someInput')
    .focus(function() {
        showFormEntryHint(this, 'Please enter your name.');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        hideHint();
    });
});
</script>
```

Barring that however, you can also look for ready-made plugins to do the brunt work for you if you don't need much custom logic.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll probably move to using this way - however I needed to figure out why my original solution didn't work properly.