# How to display a new image/window when rollover another image/link

Tags: javascript, html

I know this will be an easy one for you guys but I couldn't figure out how to do something like this; http://backpack.tf/

On that page, when you take your mouse to any item it opens a new small window displaying some text/image. What are my options for achieving something like that? JavaScript? I tried using "onMouseOut=" with HTML but it is too simple for what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to say this is almost certainly a duplicate: [Is there a JQuery tooltip plugin that supports HTML content and automatically positions tooltips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643964/is-there-a-jquery-tooltip-plugin-that-supports-html-content-and-automatically-po/14066345#14066345).  To name but one :)

Either way you should look at tooltips, a quick google search found this:

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

It should let you use html content inside the tooltop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Hover event in jQuery or javascript whatever you like and in that even write your code whatever you want to achieve etiher showing block or displaying image:-

```
$("#idOfElement").on("hover", function()
{
    ////your code
});
```

Comment: When did he say he was using jQuery;)

Comment: he is asking in the question for approach and he even mentioned javascript so i thought jQuery is fine with him :)